# packagemaker command line: ERROR no packages to build

Tags: macos, build, packagemaker

Pulling my hair out over this one (and it's pretty short, so not easy!)...

I have an existing .pmdoc file which I can't build from the command line - PackageMaker returns "ERROR: No packages to build."  On my continuous integration machine, I can build using the UI without problem (or even warning).  However the command line does not work, and the error message is not very useful.  I'm using:

```
packagemaker -d PackageMaker/myapp.pmdoc/ -o ./MyApp.pkg -v
```

This works on my dev machine.  I tried both "packagemaker" (/usr/bin/packagemaker is a symlink to /Applications/Auxilliary_Tools/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageMaker) and "/Applications/..."

Hints and tips very gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

try

/Applications/Auxiliary\ Tools/PackageMaker.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageMaker --verbose --doc myapp.pmdoc --out myapp.pkg

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that behaves just the same :-(